# using stored_procedure on django rest_framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to django and trying to use SP on my project, when I run this code it says `Expected a Response, HttpResponse or HttpStreamingResponse to be returned from the view, but received a <class 'NoneType'>`

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def saveitem(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    if request.POST.get('office_id') and request.POST.get('sem'):
        saverec = Insertserialize(data=request.data)
        saverec.office_id = request.POST.get('office_id')
        saverec.sem = request.POST.get('sem')
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select add_clearance_item('"+saverec.office_id+"','"+saverec.sem+"')")
        return Response(saverec.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class Insertserialize(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = ClearanceInsert
    fields = [
        'office_id',
        'sem',
    ]
```

Comment: If the POST data you look for in the `if` is not found then you return `None` and not a `Response` from your view

Comment: How can I check if the <if> is not found?

Comment: Add an `else:` block for the `if` that checks the post data where you raise an appropriate exception or return an appropriate error response

Comment: your right it doesn't return anything, i feel like the saverec.office_id = request.POST.get('office_id') and saverec.sem = request.POST.get('sem')
 didn't do anything at all or didn't reach the serializers.py